# Can I capture the users intent ('Save' vs 'Save and continue editing') for craft()->on('entries.saveEntry'

Tags: plugin-development, entries, plugins, php

I'm writing a plugin that gathers up all the assets from an entry and saves it out as a zip (along with a JSON file with information from the entry).  Any advice regarding a better method is appreciated, but right now I add the code in on('entries.saveEntry'), like so:

```
    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
        $entry = $event->params['entry'];
        $outputArray = array();

        /* 
        business logic filling variables removed for the sake of brevity 
        */

        if (($entry['sectionId'] == 3) && ($entry['buildPage'] == 1)) {
            file_put_contents(getcwd()."/build/videos.json", json_encode($outputArray));

            $assetGroup[] = getcwd()."/build/videos.json";
            $zipfile = craft()->buildPage->create_zip($assetGroup, $entry['uri'], getcwd()."/build/");
            $filename = substr($zipfile,strrpos($zipfile,'/')+1);

            if (file_exists($zipfile)) {
                craft()->request->sendFile($filename, file_get_contents( $zipfile ), array('forceDownload' => true), false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything works, except that my sendFile call prevents the user from being returned to the Entries page (or stating a new entry, etc.), if that was their intent.  Is it possible to capture where they were headed before I stopped them, so that I can send them on their way?  Or is that not possible the way I have things written?

Answer (score 2):

The 4th parameter to [HttpRequestService->sendFile()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#sendFile-detail) is `$terminate = true`, which will by default, terminate the request after the file is sent.

Set that to `false` and let the request continue as usual and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks Brad, but I did have it set to false.  I tried changing it to true, just to see, and it throws an error:

  "File not found
  Firefox can't find the file at /admin/entries/videoGroup/4-videotest."

Comment: What if you call `$this->redirectToPostedUrl()` from your controller after the file is sent?

Comment: No luck with that yet, but I'll keep tweaking and post back if I get a working solution.  Thanks!